# How can I read an image as a matrice with python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I am considering creating a 3-d list to represent an image to work on it. There is going to be a 3-member list for RGB values for each pixel and list of that list for the 2-d layout. How this could be achieved and also for basic image processing operations (gray conversion, cropping, canny edge etc.) is this a realistic basis to start with?

Is this a bad start?

```
def read_image_as_matrix(image_path):
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        image_content = image_file.read()

    pixel_values = [int(byte) for byte in image_content]

    # Assuming as 100:
    image_width = 100

    image_matrix = [pixel_values[i:i + image_width] for i in range(0, len(pixel_values), image_width)]

    return image_matrix


image_path = "t_image.png"
image_matrix = read_image_as_matrix(image_path)

print(len(image_matrix))
print(image_matrix)
for row in image_matrix[:len(image_matrix)]:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Yes, this is a bad start. Use a NumPy array to represent your image. This will be much more efficient memory-wise, and will allow you do apply operations to the image as a whole, instead of needing to iterate over every value in the image. Unless you want to implement image processing algorithms from scratch as a learning exercise, you should also use one of the many image processing packages available. They will all work with NumPy arrays or with objects compatible with them. I would recommend you use scikit-image, OpenCV or DIPlib instead of rolling your own functions.

Comment: Also, you cannot read a PNG file by just converting each byte into an integer. PNG files have a header, and the pixel data is compressed. [You need to parse the data in the file and make sense of it before you can get the pixel values out.](https://www.w3.org/TR/png/) Use any existing package to read and write image files. The imageio package is really neat. It will read your image into a NumPy array.

Comment: Just concurring with Cris's excellent advice.